# What can I research to back up my sound design?

Tags: recording, techniques, effects, research, experimental

I realise the question is a bit ambiguous but I couldn't think of a way to put it into one simple question.

I am currently a final year music technology student undertaking some sound design for my final year project. Now, I have taken a 'blue-sky' approach with my experimentation based project, I can experiment all day finding or recreating sound effects and recording techniques but of course I don't get marks for just talking about how I made rain with a bunch of marbles or whatever.

Now I'm not asking for someone to write my dissertation for me but I would like to know what areas I can look into to back up *WHY* I'm doing what I'm doing, for example, I have been looking into causal and reduced listening and how that would affect how I create sound effects, also when recording sound effects why did I choose a particular microphone. They still don't feel like they back up strongly enough the backbone of my project so I was wondering if any could point me in a direction or area that could possibly help me, anything at all that could be related.

This has become a little longer than expected but thank you so much for taking the time to read through this, I look forward to hearing any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of simply listing practical details about how you're making your sounds (eg. types of mics, foley techniques and so forth), you might consider making more theory-based speculations about why certain sounds, or qualities of sound, are appropriate to convey the particular messages that you're trying to convey; how they create meaning for the listener and why.

A simple example: if I created the voice of a large man, I'd want it to be many things, but probably top of the list would be deep/low-pitched. Why? Because, throughout our lives, our experience of the world has taught us that big things make deep noises, and small things make high-pitched noises. The marriage of big objects with deep sound is learned and justified by experience, and as a result, a large man with a high-pitched voice would probably strike the listener as odd and unsettling.

Have a look through Theo Van Leeuwen's Speech, Music, Sound, as a starting point.

Comment: Unless you are Mike Tyson... Though I suppose that probably works as proof of your point since his high pitched voice is frequently joked about.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for this! I've started to look into physics of sound which is kind of closely related to what you are speaking of. I suppose in a sense the physics of sound is the 'WHY' of what you said about deep/low pitched sounds. Again thanks for this and I will take a look Theo's work!

Answer (score 2):

From the top of my head, the book "Sound Design" by David Sonnenschein is a very good start! I'm on my second read-through on it myself right now :-)

Comment: I actually have bought that book and where I found reduced and causal listening! I haven't got all the way through it yet, great book so far though. I will definitely find something of use in it I'm sure, thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2):

Although the focus is on sound design for theatre, Ross Brown's *Sound: A Reader in Theatre Practice* is a brilliant resource with a wide-ranging bibliography. 'Reader'-type books are great for initial research for this very reason: someone else has gathered all the essential reading into one book!

As @Arran says, theory-based texts about why we use sound are useful. I'd also add to that that when we make sound, as sound designers we are making for an audience that *listens*, so works on the experience and meaningfulness of listening are also interesting. Try Salomé Voegelin's *Listening to Noise and Silence* and *Sonic Possible Worlds*, or for some mindbending, give Jean-Luc Nancy's *Listening* a go (disclaimer: I love that book, but it's some pretty wacky French philosophy!) The ambient composer David Toop has also written a number of fascinating books about how sound affects us as human and thinking beings.

Comment: I think I've got a hefty library session ahead of me tomorrow haha! They definitely sound interesting to look into, thanks for the help!